# Facebook Crawler infers different og:url than the one specified in the metatag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

I am trying to collect the engagement data for this page: http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787

While working on my code I realized that Facebook returns different Open Graph objects for different variations of the URL which should not happen as the page provides a canonical URL.

Example:

1. http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787
2. http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787/
3. https://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787
4. https://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787/

resolve to different Open Graph objects.

Upon inspection in the Open Graph Object Debugger I saw that the inferred canonical URL had additional parameters, e.g., http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787?error=cookies_not_supported&code=4b78fd75-8cad-4456-a877-be0c9c1b9108

---

While I am aware that the redirects failed because of some cookie action going on, the last part of the new URL `code=4b78fd75-8cad-4456-a877-be0c9c1b9108` varies for each of the 4 URL variations, which then leads to different OG objects.

Can somebody help me out here and explain why Facebook is inferring a new canonical URL (with added parameters) even though the original link had provided one?

Comment: The debug tool shows you which path is followed, and it starts with your system redirecting from `http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787` to `https://idp.nature.com/authorize?response_type=cookie&client_id=grover&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nature.com%2Fnews%2Fthe-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787`, and via a few more steps to `http://www.nature.com/news/the-future-of-dna-sequencing-1.22787?error=cookies_not_supported&code=1dfe8601-010d-4580-bfb3-ad8403e6fc3f`

Comment: And yes, while that last one has og:url set to the first URL again - why should the scraper follow that again now, it tried already and was redirected elsewhere ...

Comment: Oh, you're right. Have been staring at those debug interfaces and error messages for too long...

So basically, the setting the canonical URL does not necessarily ensure that the canonical URL used by FB will be the same one?

Comment: Not if you create a circular redirect path ...